# Internal energy change in isothermal process vs. adiabatic process with $\gamma$ approaching 1

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, adiabatic

This might be a somewhat academic question (since there's no gas with $\gamma = 1$), but I am still interested in this.

Let's consider ideal gas and polytropic process with index $n$. We know, that when $n \to 1$ we get $\mathrm{d} E = 0$, i.e. the energy is constant.

On the other hand, for adiabatic process we have the following
$$
\mathrm{d} E = - p \mathrm{d} V = - p_0 \frac{V_0^\gamma}{V^\gamma} \mathrm{d} V
$$

One integration later...
$$
E = - p_0 V_0^\gamma \int \limits_{V_0}^V \frac{\mathrm{d} V}{V^\gamma} = \frac{p_0 V_0^\gamma}{\gamma - 1} \left( \frac{1}{V^{\gamma-1}} - \frac{1}{V_0^{\gamma-1}} \right) = \frac{p V}{\gamma-1} \left( 1 - \left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)^{\gamma-1} \right)
$$
In the limit where $\gamma \to 1$ we get
$$
E = p V \log (V_0 / V)
$$

Isn't this a bit of a contradiction? If $n = 1$ (isothermal process) we get $E = \text{const}.$, however, if $n = \gamma$ and we let $\gamma \to 1$, then $E = p V \log (V_0 / V)$ which is not a constant. Note that $\gamma$ doesn't have to be strictly 1, we get a curve that's close to $p V \log V$ even when $\gamma = 1.1$.

Comment: There is no contradictions. When you do the integration, you already have to assume that $\gamma$ is not 1. If you take any other value of $\gamma$ other than 1, (even if you take 1.000001) , it will still not be isothermal.

Answer (score 1):

See the mistake here you are doing is, taking $\gamma$ as just a coefficient. The thing is that $\gamma$ is a special value and is different for different gases, you can't just say I'll set it to 1, hence there is absolutely no controversy here. Because if you are setting $\gamma$ as  ( which is theoretically impossible due to Mayer's relation) you are saying your process is a reversible isothermal, as well as adiabatic process.

Comment: Okay, well, I guess the resolution then is "this specific order of limits (first adiabatic and then $\gamma \to 1$ yields a weird unphysical process that tries to be both isothermal and adiabatic". Still, it'd be interesting to see what kind of gas (doesn't need to be a common gas found on Earth, could be something relevant to MHD) has $\gamma$ closest to 1 and then marvel at how the "almost isothermal" process still has a non-constant energy...

Comment: @user16320 lowest value for $\gamma$ for ideal gas that I recall seeing was 1.33.

Comment: You can readily find gasses with lower adiabatic index https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-ratio-d_608.html
It is, however, up to further research which of them can be modeled as ideal.

Comment: In my undergrad I was told that most gasses can be modeled as ideal. Seeing van der Waals equation of state I'd still say that even more complicated gas can be modeled as ideal far away from the phase changes, i.e. far away from the non-linearities. So now I've found you $\gamma$ very close to 1 (as low as 1.04) :) is it still not aligned with reality?

Comment: @user16320 I have a hard time believing that gases like N-Heptane $C_{7}H_{16}$ with $\gamma$ =1.04 and other such large polyatomic gases with low values of $\gamma$ could exhibit ideal gas behavior, i.e., act like point masses. Not saying it’s impossible, but can you find any? I found the equation of state for a couple to be quite complex. In any case, this answer is similar to mine. Let’s see what else you get.

Comment: @user16320 see the point is that $\gamma$ is a special number, and there is a reason to why $\gamma$ can never be 1. It is strictly impossible to find any gas ( showing ideal behaviour ) to have the value of $\gamma$ as 1

Comment: @S K Dash just to be clear you are not talking about $n$, the polytropic index in general, which can take on any value between zero and infinity,  but $n$ = $\gamma$ = $\frac{C_p}{Cv}$ which is a special case where the polytropic index is for a reversible adiabatic process, correct?

Comment: @S K Dash I should add that the polytropic index $n$, with exception of an adiabatic process, is not a ratio of specific heats

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction. Your final equation is in fact the work done for an ideal gas isothermal process, not the change in internal energy. When you made $\gamma=n=1$, $\gamma$ is no longer the ratio of specific heats because you changed the process from adiabatic to isothermal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But $n = \gamma$ (regardless of value of $\gamma$) corresponds to the adiabatic process, not isothermal...

Comment: My point is, that when $\gamma$ decreases, the function for internal energy smoothly approaches $p V \log V$ and not a constant. What if the gas has $20$ degrees of freedom? Then $\gamma = 1.1$ and $E$ is not any closer to a constant than for $\gamma = 1.66$.

Comment: No it doesn’t, because n=1 is unique for an isothermal process and is no longer the ratio of specific heats, which in turn is unique to an adiabatic process. For all other (than adiabatic) polytropic processes $n$ is not a ratio of specific heats and can have a value anywhere from zero to infinity.

Comment: Another thing. Your adiabatic process equation only applies to ideal gases wher the range of $\gamma$ is limited, For air it’s 1.4.

Comment: I feel like all of this is just avoiding the mathematical point of this exercise. There's so many things in physics we consider and ponder about which are not quite aligned with the nature... Sure, you can't have a delta-function temperature profile yet people solve heat equation with such initial condition because Green's function is very useful (but nature doesn't know about delta functions and in fact, the heat equation would no longer be valid for such spatial dependence). I can think of many other examples where the model is quite simplified yet useful.

Comment: Nevertheless, your mathematically based conclusion does not align with reality and I’ve tried to show you why. But you are, of course, free to reject it and wait for an answer that confirms your discovery of a contradiction in thermodynamics. I look forward to seeing the responses you get. Good luck.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, but the "discovery" is not mine to "claim". $\gamma = 1$ is sometimes used in MHD simulations as a quick and dirty way to keep $T$ constant but have some nontrivial formula for internal energy (instead of 0 we use $\rho \log \rho$) at the same time (I only now noticed this contradiction and no one around me cares to address it). Thanks, I'm looking forward to seeing them, too!

Comment: Look, I’m open to reconsider this if I see a convincing argument. I’m going to run this by a thermodynamics mentor of mine and see what he thinks.

Comment: @Chet Miller Hi Chet. Does the OP have a point here?

Comment: See the thing is that n can never be equal to 1, it might get very close to but never be equal

Comment: @S K Dash n=1 for an isothermal process